# Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada) conversão de decimal para binario

Tags: c, conversão, decimal, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

int d;
int bits = 8;
int vetor[bits];
int a = bits - 1;
int b = a;

    scanf("%d", &d);

    if(d >= 2) {
    while(d/2 > 0){
        vetor[a] = b % 2;
        b /= 2;
        a--;
        b--;
        }

    for(a=0; a<b; a++)
        vetor[a] = 0;
    vetor[b] = 1;
    for(a=0; a<bits; b++)
    printf("%d", vetor[a]);
    }

        else if(d >= 1) {
                for(a=0; a<b; a++)
    printf("%d", vetor[a] = 0);
    printf("%d", vetor[a] = 1);
    }

    else if(d >= 0) {
                for(a=0; a<bits; a++)
    printf("%d", vetor[b] = 0);

    }
    else printf("\n Numero invalido!");

    printf("\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você percebeu que no laço de impressão você está atribuindo o valor 0 para `vetor[b]`? E, portanto, não imprimindo o valor de `vetor[b]`?

Comment: não sei o que poderia fazer para corrigir o errou, mesmo alterando o valor da o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em `while(d/2 > 0){
            vetor[a] = b % 2;
            b /= 2;
            a--;
            b--;
        }`

troque vetor[a] = b % 2; por vetor[a] = d % 2 e 
troque b /= 2; por d /=2;

Em `for(a=0; a<bits; b++)
        printf("%d", vetor[a]);`
troque b++ por a++

Comment: deu certo muito obg